# ProgressBar Update in two Activities

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have two Activities, BookStoreActivity and BookDetailActivity. In BookStoreActivity, when I click on BookItem, it will go to BookDetailActivity. In BookDetailActivity, when I click "Download" book, it will show download progress in BookDetailActivity.

I also want to show progress update in BookItem's of BookStoreActivity. The two progress update must be the same. Now I'm using [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) from loopj.com. It is look like Google Play App Downloading process.

Please see the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F5g1.png. First is App's Detail and Second is My AppList, I want to like that.

Comment: Simple send progress update message to both activity progressbar..!!

Comment: I am not sure I see a question here. May we see some of your existing code?

Comment: When downloading app from Google Play, it show the download progress (progress bar) in App's Detail,My Apps and in other UI...and then when enter again to downloading app it show(resume) the downloading progress bar.I want to do like that